# Compiling lot of .c files to .o files using makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I want to compile all .c files to .o files except some of them. Any help?
Currently my commands are looking like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -C -o $(CFLAGS) $@ $^
```

but I made a

```
EXCEPTIONS2 = testadmin.c testclient.c testserver.c server_comm.c client_comm.c
TO_COMPILE = $(filter-out $(EXCEPTIONS2), $(wildcard *.c))
```

But i dont know how to put them together, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a target that depends on those files. You can, for example, get all files in a directory like

```
SOURCEDIR := Some/Directory/You/Like
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c')
EXCEPTIONS2 = testadmin.c testclient.c testserver.c server_comm.c client_comm.c
TO_COMPILE = $(filter-out $(EXCEPTIONS2), $(SOURCES))
```

and then do something like:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -C -o $(CFLAGS) $@ $^

all: $(TO_COMPILE:%.c=%.o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a target that depends on the object files you want to be created:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(TO_COMPILE:%.c=%.o)
```

and that's all.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the way, can you show me exaclty?

Comment: I mean, just add the lines I show above to your makefile.